# Fast Way to Populate Multiple ComboBoxes in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am developing a Windows Forms application in VB.NET using .NET 4.7.2. On a tab page of a Tab Control I have 40 ComboBox controls with a DropDownStyle of "DropDown." When I enter the tab I want to query the database and get the results. There are a little over 5K strings returned.  This operation doesn't take much time at all. I then want all the ComboBoxes to use the same List, DataTable, or BindingList for the available Items. Each ComboBox should be allowed to select a different value, without updating all the other ComboBoxes.  Every way I have tried this is VERY slow. I have tried List(Of String), DataTable, and BindingList(Of String); where I set the RaiseListChangeEvents to False before setting the DataSource. I have also tried setting the DisplayMember property of the ComboBox to "Text" before and after setting the DataSource property. None of it has sped up the process.

This is my current code:

```
    Private Sub RefreshBOXNComboBoxes()
    Dim lFibersMaster As List(Of String) = GetFISFiberIDs()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 40
        Dim strControlName As String = "cboBOXN_Slot_" & i.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0")
        Dim objCombo As ComboBox = DirectCast(tpBOXN.Controls(strControlName), ComboBox)
        Dim blFibers As New BindingList(Of String)(lFibersMaster)
        blFibers.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
        With objCombo
            .DataSource = blFibers
            .DisplayMember = "Text"
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With
    Next
End Sub
Private Function GetFISFiberIDs() As List(Of String)
    Dim ret As New List(Of String)()
    Dim strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FIS").ConnectionString
    Using conFIS As New OracleConnection(strConnectionString)
        conFIS.Open()

        Dim strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT SERIAL_FIBER_ID FROM FIS.FIB_DATA_HEADER ORDER BY SERIAL_FIBER_ID"
        Using cmdFIS As New OracleCommand(strSQL, conFIS)
            Using drFIS As OracleDataReader = cmdFIS.ExecuteReader()
                While drFIS.Read()
                    ret.Add(drFIS("SERIAL_FIBER_ID").ToString())
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        conFIS.Close()
    End Using
    Return ret
End Function
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do. Filling 40 ComboBoxes with more than 5000 items will take time no matter what you do.

Comment: The problem is with the design. A ComboBox isn't designed to maintain that number of items (let alone 40 at the same time). Consider using a preloaded HashSet and then use the ComboBoxes to search and populate dynamically.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed - Can you please post an answer / example of how to do this? Currently, all the ComboBoxes have an AutoCompleteMode of "Suggest" and an AutoCompleteSource of "ListItems" Are you getting at using an AutoCompleteCustomSource instead?

Comment: Setting `blFibers.RaiseListChangedEvents = False` is useless. When you assign the DataSource, a BindingList is created internally: this is the list that raises ListChanged events, eventually, not yours. Set the `DisplayMember` **before** setting the DataSource: if you set it after, you cause the DataSource to be rewired, so you do it twice (per ComboBox). It's also completely useless here (just strings). You can use `async` loading, as shown in the two examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103) (it can be applied in the background). `5000` items is not actually that much.

Comment: In the code that I linked, the ComboBox is filled with the maximum number of elements: `65534`, with a *fake* delay, in a `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` block. But you cannot avoid a somewhat slow response here. If you want to speed up the process, you need to change your design, making it more *rational* (hence, probably, more *user-friendly*).

Comment: How easy is it for the user to select one of the 5000 items? Is there some way that you could reduce the number of items in those comboboxes - even if it means adding another combobox?

Comment: @Jimi I have seen several warnings about the order of assigning DataSource and DisplayMember but I had never seen an explanation of. Thank you.

Comment: @Mary  You can see it in the Reference source: when the DisplayMember changes, [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,2944), follow the `RefreshItems()` method and in the ListControl (the ComboBox List) [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,137), follow `SetDataConnection()`, which is called after `DisplayMember` is set. This property defines how the List elements are displayed: if it changes, the List needs to be rebuilt to reflect the change

Comment: @Jimi Thanks again. I do like the Reference Source but it is hard for me to read because of the unfamiliar types, interfaces etc.. This really clears it up. I always thought "What good is a DisplayMember without a DataSource. Of course I am just setting a property. Its value is of no significance until the source is set.

Comment: @Mary Yes, that's how it is. `DisplayMember` sets a value that is used to determine how the elements in the data source should be displayed. If the property is not set, the List items are shown, in practice, calling `[Object].ToString()` and the visible List is created this way. If you change the `DisplayMember` value (maybe specifying a Property or Column name), the List needs to be reset to generate the new *View* (unless the `DisplayMember` value set is the same as before).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over the TabPage's controls and set each ComboBox's datasource to the `List(Of String)`.

```
Private Sub RefreshBOXNComboBoxes()
    Dim lFibersMaster As List(Of String) = GetFISFiberIDs()
    For Each cb As ComboBox In TabPage1.Controls().OfType(Of ComboBox)
        cb.DataSource = lFibersMaster
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The process will still be slow. Plus, OP said they've already tried using `List(Of String)`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I don't think this will be a slow process at all because you are not copying items to the `Items` collection but simply assigning the datasource property to something.

Comment: It will. Try it yourself. _"but simply assigning the datasource property to something"_ which leads to changing the `Items` collection. See my comments to the question above for alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking some of your suggestions and came to the determination that a ComboBox was probably not the right control for storing over 5K of ListItems.  Instead, I switched the 40 ComboBoxes to 40 TextBoxes. I set the AutoCompleteMode to "Suggest" and the AutoCompleteSource to "Custom Source" for all 40 of them. With Suggestion tuned on, it really acts like a ComboBox, is really fast, and does what I need it to do.

```
Public colFISFibers As AutoCompleteStringCollection
Private Sub RefreshBOXNFISFiberControls()
    Dim lFibersMaster As List(Of String) = GetFISFiberIDs()
    colFISFibers = New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    colFISFibers.AddRange(lFibersMaster.ToArray())

    For i As Integer = 1 To 40
        Dim strControlName As String = "txtBOXN_Slot_" & i.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0")
        Dim objTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(tpBOXN.Controls(strControlName), TextBox)
        With objTextBox
            .AutoCompleteCustomSource = colFISFibers
            .Text = String.Empty
        End With
    Next
End Sub
Private Function GetFISFiberIDs() As List(Of String)
    Dim ret As New List(Of String)()
    Dim strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FIS").ConnectionString
    Using conFIS As New OracleConnection(strConnectionString)
        conFIS.Open()

        Dim strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT SERIAL_FIBER_ID FROM FIS.FIB_DATA_HEADER ORDER BY SERIAL_FIBER_ID"
        Using cmdFIS As New OracleCommand(strSQL, conFIS)
            Using drFIS As OracleDataReader = cmdFIS.ExecuteReader()
                While drFIS.Read()
                    ret.Add(drFIS("SERIAL_FIBER_ID").ToString())
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        conFIS.Close()
    End Using
    Return ret
End Function
```