# Getting error "Cannot access a disposed object" after checking .IsDisposed() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, task

To track progress on a long-running async task in my VB.NET app, I create a small form that contains a ProgressBar control.  The task updates the ProgressBar via Invoke, and I check to make sure the control is not Nothing and also that it is not IsDisposed.  The idea is that the user can close the ProgressBar form if they don't want to watch it slowly tick towards completion.

However in testing, I closed the form and then got an error "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object."  My guess here is that the form closed while the update was occurring. That is, after I checked if it was OK but before it completed.

```
Private Sub Btn_StoreForceStale_Click(sender As Button, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_StoreForceStale.Click
    Dim pb As ProgressBar = GetProgressPopUp("Force Refreshing All Stale Items in Inventory")
    EnableButtons(False)
    Dim x As Task = Task.Run(Sub() RefreshPrices(True,, pb)).ContinueWith(Sub() EnableButtons(True))
End Sub

Public Sub RefreshPrices(Optional force As Boolean = False, Optional PriceAge As Integer = -1, Optional progBar As TextProgressBar = Nothing)
'Actual price refreshing Code
        If Not (progBar Is Nothing OrElse progBar.IsDisposed) Then
            progBar.Invoke(Sub() progBar.Increment(1))  '<-- Error happens here
        End If
End Sub
```

After the crash and I'm in debug, I can see that progBar.IsDisposed is true and so the increment should not happen. That's why I believe the form closing happened during the increment itself.

Is there a way to avoid this? A way in the Form.Closing event to check if a control is being invoked and delay closing until it's not? Or is something else going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Fundamental threading race bug, no guarantee whatsoever that IsDisposed is still *False* by the time the invoked code runs.  No guarantee either that the invoked code even runs, it does purge the invoke queue, but you don't care about that when you use BeginInvoke().  Always choose BeginInvoke.  You must test it in the invoked code to fix the bug.  No race, that runs on the same thread as the Dispose() call.

Comment: Read the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103), and see the first method: note the `Form.FormClosing` handler (it applies to all the other methods shown there). Don't use `Invoke()` (possibly, ever - that `.ContinueWith()` + `Invoke()` is really looking for trouble, more than what you're experiencing here). `Control.IsDisposed` is not thread-safe, you cannot determine whether a Control is disposed inspecting that property from a worker thread. Neither is `IsHandleCreated`. It applies to all Controls, Forms included.

Comment: Note that when you call `Invoke()`, it looks for a marshaller: if none can be found (always the case when the Form is being disposed), it throws the exception back to the caller thread, so right in your face; `BeginInvoke()` throws an exception that bubbles up to the CLR as an `unhandled exception`.

Comment: @Jimi I'm reading through your very detailed answer in the linked question so I'll see if I can understand it enough to apply to my situation. However I am excited to also apply it to a number of very slow loading comboboxes I have that I thought I'd just need to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid this?

Yes. There are many ways. One option is to use `Progress(Of T)` to handle updates. Create the instance of the class in the UI thread before you start the task. It will capture the current synchronization context and use that instead of trying to invoke through a specific UI object.

Another way is to use a variable to indicate whether the progress should be reported or not. You can handle the `FormClosed` event to set the variable. If you do this though, you need to use some kind of synchronization (e.g. [`SyncLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement)) to ensure that the progress update occurs only when the variable is `False`, and that the UI thread can't set it to `True` until after the call to `BeginInvoke()` occurs. Note that you *must* use `BeginInvoke()` in this approach because you need to hold the lock while you're making the call, and if you used `Invoke()` in that situation, the call would deadlock.

As you might guess, I prefer the `Progress(Of T)` option. :) It seems a lot less messy to me.

Finally, there's not enough context in your question to know if it would be possible to use [`Async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/async) and [`Await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator). But if you can recompose your long-running task as a loop that uses `Task.Run()` for each iteration, awaiting that and then updating the progress bar, this would IMHO be the ideal approach. Note that each iteration of the loop need not correspond to a single unit of work; you could (and should, if a single unit of work is small) do the work in batches, so that you don't make the transition between worker thread and UI thread too frequently.

Comment: Progress(Of T) works great with Task.Run, thanks! I tried Jimi's approach to use Progress with async/await and couldn't get it to call the handler.  FWIW in my testing, each unit of work is running about 1100ms so that's definitely not too frequent for updates.