# Restrict text typed in Autocomplete to only valid strings in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete

Working in VB.NET, I have a TextBox with AutoComplete, and the AutoCompleteCustomSource is 91,000 records long.

I'd like to restrict the text entered to only strings that are included in the AutoCompleteStringCollection.  For example, if the list is days of the week, the user could type in "M" - "O" - "N", but if the next key is "f", it will get rejected.

I found only this suggestion of how to do it in ASP (https://forums.asp.net/t/2055327.aspx?Autocomplete+restrict+user+to+select+only+from+the+list+coming) which led me down the path to using the TxtBox.TextChanged event to compare the typed text to the list.

However I've found that I can't use LINQ with AutoCompleteStringCollection, so I can't use TxtBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AsQueryable.Any(function(x) x.Contains(TxtBox.Text))

How can I quickly check the Text contents of the control to the entire 91,000 item list?

Comment: If limiting users to only the values in your AutoCompleteCustomSource, wouldn't it be a better idea use a combo/dropdown list?

Comment: It would be, yes, but loading 91,000 records into a Combobox DataSource takes about 5-6 seconds that blocks the UI. (Time to set the DataSource, not prepare the data beforehand). So I thought I'd try this

Comment: If you're referring to a WinForms UI, see the notes and a couple of methods to defer the presentation of a collection of Items: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103). It can be applied to a ComboBox, maybe with an `AutoCompleteSource` set to `ListItems`, but also to a `List<string>` that composes the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` of a TextBox.