# vb.net threading and loading panel

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loading

Im trying to use vb.net threading in order to avoid form freezing and load datagridview data separately

I have Main form Called **home** where there is a button when i click it summons another form called **Formone** which contains charts and datagridview.

```
Dim trr As System.Threading.Thread
    Private Sub Formone_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ProgressPanel1.Show() '// this is loading GIF
        trr = New Thread(AddressOf load_dgv)
        trr.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
        trr.Start()

        stats() '/ this is chartcontrol 


    End Sub

        Private Sub load_dgv()
            'here sql server query and load it to a table
        end sub 

      Sub assignit(ByVal x As DataTable)

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then

        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of DataTable)(AddressOf assignit), x)
    Else


        GridControl1.DataSource = x

        

        ProgressPanel1.Hide()
    End If
```

the data loads normally to the datagridview and also charts but the form freezes while data is being loaded and the loading gif doesnt show up , also the button freezes.

i want to show the loading gif while data is being loaded and avoid that freezing.

Comment: Second example here: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103). Read also the notes in the first example, which can be used as well here, just changing the return value and the Controls types. If you have a lot of data to load and show, use the DataGridView's VirtualMode.

Comment: An option that precedes the introduction of `Tasks` is the `BackgroundWorker`. You can query the database in the `DoWork` event handler to populate a `DataTable` and assign that to the `e.Result` property, then get it back from the `e.Result` property in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler and bind it to your grid.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Could you show a code example of that ? and what about loading animation ?

Comment: What do you not understand about the examples you found for yourself when you searched?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the reason why this happens:

Animations can only be processed in the UI thread.

I had this issue with my application.

Heres what you do:

In your UI Thread:

`SplashScreen.Show` 'which has your animation/logo/gif

and you will need to put a wait function right after it while your worker thread loads you data.

Goto to your toolbox in vb and select BACKGROUND WORKER. Double click your background worker object and it will take you to the BackgrounderWOrker_DoWork() section

There is where you do all your loading.

Back to your UI Thread:

```
Splash.Show
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync 'execute the background worker
While BackGroundWorker.IsBusy = True 'wait for the background worker
Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

With this,  your gif will display smoothlty as it runs on the UI Thread, and your backgrounder worker loads your data.
.

Comment: thanks i already did that but the problem is the form freezes before i even start loading the data into datagridview it seems like ui elements (charts,labels...etc ) are loading slowly