# Explorer freezes when dragging folder until VB event is finished

Tags: windows, vb.net, explorer

I'm making a program in VB.NET, which does some file processing on a folder that is dragged into the form control. When the folder is dropped, all I *really* need is the path to it, and then explorer can go about its day. But the event that the drop calls (Me.DragDrop) freezes the explorer instance that the folder was dragged from until my work is done. Here's what I've got:

```
Public Sub FileEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
End Sub

Public Sub FileDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    dropPath = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String()).First
    Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(dropPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    . . .
End Sub
```

once I have dropPath, I don't need the drop event anymore, but it holds on.

Comment: Since, unfortunately, there isn't an async version of `GetFiles()` and `EnumerateFiles()` may not help much if you start to parse the results right after, you can resort to run a Task and do something with the result, using a form of Progress - if you need to update the UI - or just read the results when the Task returns. See the last method here: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103), it should do the job. (You need to make your `FileDrop` handler `Async` and `Await Task.Run()`, passing the root path dropped from Explorer to the method)

Comment: Of course you don't need to pass a Control reference if you don't need to show the results in a UI. Just process the files paths there. -- Note that the fourth method shown there is a semi-fake Async method. It works asynchronously, though, as far as your main Thread is concerned.