# Multi-Threading (Calling Sub From WorkerThread)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Need to call a sub that is coded written inside the block of form1 form an external worker thread.  This is what I have written:

In Form1:

```
Public Delegate Sub UpdateControlDelegate(ByVal C As Label, ByVal txt As String)
    Private Sub UpdateControl(ByVal C As Label, ByVal txt As String)
        If C.InvokeRequired Then
            C.Invoke(New UpdateControlDelegate(AddressOf UpdateControl), New Object() {C, txt})

        Else
         C.Text = txt
        End If
    End Sub

Public Sub DoStuff()
'we do some stuff then when it comnes time update a certain control:
Call UpdateControl(MyLabel, "My Text For The Label)
End Sub
```

In The workerThread that is located in a class:

```
Public Class MyClass

Public Sub UpdateData
Call Form1.DoStuff
End Sub
End Class
```

Does this look correct?  The most simplest terms on what I am trying to achieve:

WorkerThread to call a Sub that is located in Class Form1
and that sub contains code that updates a couple controls in Form1.

Comment: Where is that second code snippet located? If it's in `Form1` then you should be using `Me` rather than `Form1`. The latter uses the default instance and that is thread-specific.

Comment: @jmcihinney, I appreciate your help in all my questions.  the 2nd snippet is located in another class.

Comment: Pass a [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate to the worker Thread. Call its [Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report) method to pass values to the delegate. The actual delegate is your `DoSomeStuff()` method, declared in the UI Thread. Remove `Public Delegate Sub DelegateOfDoSomeStuff()`. -- First example here: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103)

Comment: You can use a `SynchronizationContext` in that class and then use it to marshal to the UI thread within that class. At that point, you can use the default instance of `Form1` if that is indeed the instance that has already been displayed, e.g. it is the startup form.

Comment: Form1 does not work in a worker thread, you get a new *instance* of the Form1 *class*.  You can't see it, its Show() method was never called.  Get it right, but if you absolutely have to then use Application.OpenForms(0).Invoke

Comment: I have updated the code,  I think this is one of the ways to do it as I do not understand SyncContext and progress(of t).

Comment: damn this still does not work.  what am I missing?

Comment: Figured it out myself, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a little more research.  I have figured it out.   The initial code I have written is correct.  The only thing missing is a reference to the form I need to update.

Here is the COMPLETE solution when needing to run a SUB from the UI that is called from the Worker Thread:

```
Public Class MyClass
'working thread is being within the subs of this class
Public MyForm1111 As Form1  '<------ The variable in this class that will reference to the form1 that we need

Public Sub MySubThatIsOnAWorkerThread
MyForm1111.DoStuff  '<==== must call MyForm1111.DoStuff and NOT Form1.DoStuff
End Sub

End Class

The Sub Located In Form1:

Public Class Form1


Public Delegate Sub UpdateControlDelegate(ByVal C As Label, ByVal txt As String) 'Required Delegate
    


Private Sub UpdateControl(ByVal C As Label, ByVal txt As String) 'Sub to update controls
            If C.InvokeRequired Then
                C.Invoke(New UpdateControlDelegate(AddressOf UpdateControl), New Object() {C, txt})
    
            Else
             C.Text = txt
            End If
        End Sub
    
Public Sub DoStuff() 'the sub we need to call from the worker thread
'do some calculations and code
Call UpdateControl(MyLabel, "Some Text For Label")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load()
MyClass.MyForm1111 = Me  <==== Set the reference here in your Form1_Load
End Sub
End Class
```