# How do I wait for a worker process to finish but also limit it's time to do so?

Tags: windows, vb.net, service

I am writing a Windows service in VB.Net that will go out to some devices and data log points of information.  I am using a Background Worker to do that so the service itself is still responsive. I have a timer that runs every second and checks the minute component of the current time.  Each time the minute component changes I check which devices need to be checked, some are every minute, some every 5, some every 10, etc.  These processes can take a few seconds or over a minute (I only rerun the worker if it's not already running and log a error if the last process took longer then the data retrieval interval).

In my OnStop event for the service I want to make sure the workers all close down.  I call CancelAsync on the worker and the worker checks for cancellation to hopefully exit cleanly (i.e., check cancelation, if false retrieve data, save data into database, loop).

My problem is I don't want to use a sleep statement as it will lock everything but I also don't want the service to never shut down.  So for example I have this currently:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    My.Application.Log.WriteEntry("ServiceABC shutting down for device " & DeviceID)
    ServiceTimer.enable = false
    If DataRetrievalBackgroundWorker.IsBusy Then
        DataRetrievalBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        While ((DataRetrievalBackgroundWorker.IsBusy) Or (x < 15))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            x += 1
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

This should work since the background worker is on another thread correct?  Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Use a Task instead of a BackGroundWorker, await for it, pass a CancellationToken with a timeout set with its CancellationTokenSource. The `ReportProgress` procedure is replaced passing an almost identical `Progress<T>` delegate and calling its `Report()` method. A completion result can be returned in the `T` object of `Task<T>`, if needed.

Comment: I've never used a Task before but I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: Some different examples here: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103). It would be quite important to know what kind of operations you're currently performing in the `DoWork` handler, whether you call `ReportProgress()` and with what data and what happens when the BGW terminates (i,e, if you're performing other actions in `RunWorkerCompleted`). In general, if you're doing IO-bound work or CPU-bound work.

Comment: The current BGW is going out to URL's, grabbing data, and plugging it into a SQL database.  It's looping through a extensive list of URLs, sometimes up to 2k, but the data retrieved is small (20 characters give or take). It does not support `ReportProgress` currently and the only thing in the `RunWorkerCompleted` is a lastrun variable that gets updated with date.now so I can track how long it's taking to run.

Comment: So, IO-bound, which also supports the async/await pattern, since you have all awaitable methods. Not clear what you're doing with the data you download. Just update a database, all inside the `DoWork` handler? Database updates are also (usually) awaitable (e.g., `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync()`, `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(()` etc.) and have overloads that accept a CancellationToken (hence, implicitly, also a timeout, since this is set by the CancellationTokenSource that creates the CancellationToken).

Comment: In this case, you can run a Task or use an async method. In either case, passing a CancellationToken with a pre-set timeout. If you use the latter, `await` captures the SynchrnizationContext, so - if you need to access UI elements - there's no need to Invoke, you're on the same Thread. `BeginInvoke()` can still be used, to post to the message loop without waiting for the method to complete (so the call is *asynchronous*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, if you don't want to Sleep(1000) and lock things up, do a Sleep(1).

```
    'Dim x As Integer = 0
    'While ((DataRetrievalBackgroundWorker.IsBusy) Or (x < 15))
    '    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    '    x += 1
    'End While

    Dim T As Date = Now.AddSeconds(15)
    While DataRetrievalBackgroundWorker.IsBusy Or Now() < T
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
```

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I could do that too.  The real question is should it matter if I'm using a background worker for the actual work....a sleep(1000) "shouldn't" prevent it from finishing since it's on its own thread, right?  Other option is look into the task thing as posted by @Jimi which I'm still trying to figure out.

Comment: I forgot to add the DoEvents...and yes, the background worker will not be block anyway.

Comment: I don't like tasks, once you go tasks, you can't go back. I can turn a sub into a thread and call it anyway I want. You can't do that with tasks. Once a sub is a task, it's a only a task.