# How could I go about running access querys on a seperate thread?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have an app that uses querys for most of its functions, and when the query executes the app ui "freezes". It loads fairly quickly but as it happens many times it gets annoying quick. My app pretty much always uses a class sub to execute the querys. Is there a way to run that class sub on another thread and just return the datatable to the main thread? As im still inexperienced, i never touched threading or the backgroundworker, but from a bit of testing it gives and exception for  cross thread operation not valid, and just generally i havent found any good info on how to set up threading for access. This is my sub on the class that executes the query :

```
Public Sub AddParams(Name As String, value As String, Optional datatype As OleDb.OleDbType = OleDbType.WChar)
    Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, datatype)
    NewParam.Value = value
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub

Public Sub ExecuteQuery(query As String)
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""

    Try
        DBconnection.Open()

        DBcmd = New OleDbCommand(query, DBconnection)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBcmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()
        DBdatatable = New DataTable
        DBdataadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBcmd)
        RecordCount = DBdataadapter.Fill(DBdatatable)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    If DBconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Edit:
After some trying i still cant figure it out so i thought id just post my code after Jimi's suggestion to modify it to be async:

```
Public Async Function ExecuteQueryAsync(query As String) As Task(Of DataTable)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""
    Try

        Using dbconn As New OleDbConnection([my connectionstring])
            DBcmd = New OleDbCommand(query, dbconn)
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBcmd.Parameters.Add(p))
            Params.Clear()
            Await dbconn.OpenAsync
            dt.Load(Await DBcmd.ExecuteReaderAsync)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    If DBconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBconnection.Close()
    Return dt
End Function
```

And here is the code that uses the query in a usercontrol:

```
Private Async Sub Search(Nev As String)
    Access.AddParams("@nev", "%" & Nev & "%")

    dgv.DataSource = Await Access.ExecuteQueryAsync("SELECT * from DT_ugyfelek WHERE Név LIKE @nev")
    Dim f As notification = New notification
    If NotEmpty(Access.Exception) Then f.SetAlert(Access.Exception, notification.AlertTypeEnum.Error) : Exit Sub
    dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight = 75
    dgv.Columns(0).Visible = False
    dgv.Columns(1).Width = 230
    dgv.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Név"
    'i also set 10 other headertexts here
End Sub

Private Async Sub search_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles search_btn.Click
    Search(search_txtbx.Text)
End Sub
```

By the way it loads about 20k rows. Honestly all my intention with this is to have a loading gif or something like that so the user would know that something is happening.

Comment: You can use the async version of the methods you're using now (as `OpenAsync()` and `ExecuteReaderAsync` which can replace `DBdataadapter.Fill()` in your code).  See the second example here: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103) -- Note: with a MS-Access db, you should never even try to store the Connection object: create it in-place and dispose of it as shown in the example.

Comment: Of course there's no need to call the `async` method that returns a DataTable from the `Shown` event (assuming you have a WinForms Project, you need to specify the GUI platform) as that code is doing: you can query your database using any other event handler (e.g., a `Button.Click` handler) or any other method that can `await` the result (the DataTable).

Comment: Even after setting the sub(that uses the async query for itself to fill a dgv) to be async it still locks up, shouldnt that not happen?

Comment: This all depends on how you adapted that code in your procedure. Note that only event handlers can be `async void` (an `Async Sub`), other methods cannot (you need an `Async Function`). -- Maybe show what you have written. -- If you load a lot of Rows, there's no way to avoid some *stuttering*, unless you paginate your queries.  You didn't say what uses that DataTable, your code does nothing with it.

Comment: Connections need to be disposed. The vb.net provides `Using...End Using` blocks to handle this. Declare your connections in the method where they are used.

Comment: Edited my question with my new code

Comment: I changed both the Search sub to function and the button to await, but its still the exact same... I think i did have the connectionstring correctly in the using statement i just removed my connectionstring to post it here.

Comment: You also need to `await Search(...)` in `search_btn_Click`.  -- The `Search(...)` method should return a DataTable that you assign to a DataGridView. It's not its responsibility to configure the Control. -- Remove this thing: `If DBconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBconnection.Close()` from that method: the Connection is declared with an `Using` statement, that also closes the connection. -- *Separation of Concerns* (if you don't know what that is, look it up) is very important in this kind of stuff; don't make your async methods *touch* UI elements at all in this setup.

Comment: I just forgot to remove the connectionclose because i just modified my original code, but i did so now. The way i have it set up the search function is only used here, but i did set it up so that it only does the query and returns the datatable and moved the rest to the button. still the same. i think ill give up on this one, but i very much appreciate the help

Comment: @Jimi, I don't think that `OleDb` provides those async alternatives. I think that they are specific to `SqlClient` and any other provider that cares to implement them itself. Unlike the synchronous methods, they are not inherited from the base classes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The base classes, DbConnection and DbCommand etc. (System.Data.Common) implement those methods. It's just `Task.FromResult()`.

Comment: @Jimi, that explains it. Should have looked closer.