# Form Unresponsive While Async Tasks are Completing

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a windows form that takes some time to load the values from the database into some comboboxes (3 comboboxes).  In an attempt to get the form up, I added some async code to await the loading of each combobox.  The goal is to load the form and assign the datasource/re-enable the comboboxes as the data comes through without blocking the form while the combobox datasources are being assigned.

Even with the async calls, the form is blocked until all the datasources for the comboboxes have been loaded.

Any advice to point me in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

```
private void FrmOrderSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set everything disabled to let the user know we're working on getting the long running data
    cbLanguages.DataSource = null;
    cbLanguages.Items.Clear();
    cbLanguages.Items.Add("Retrieving...");
    cbLanguages.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cbLanguages.Enabled = false;

    cbInterpreter.DataSource = null;
    cbInterpreter.Items.Clear();
    cbInterpreter.Items.Add("Retrieving...");
    cbInterpreter.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cbInterpreter.Enabled = false;

    cbCustomer.DataSource = null;
    cbCustomer.Items.Clear();
    cbCustomer.Items.Add("Retrieving...");
    cbCustomer.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cbCustomer.Enabled = false;

    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}

//added so that form renders before async stuff starts
private async void FrmOrderSearch_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.DoEvents(); //finish everything up before doing async loads

    await getCustomersAsync();
    await getInterpretersAsync();
    await getLanguagesAsync();
}

private async Task getLanguagesAsync()
{
    cbLanguages.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => MemoryObjects.LanguagesList);

    cbLanguages.ValueMember = "Code";
    cbLanguages.DisplayMember = "Language";
    cbLanguages.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cbLanguages.Enabled = true;
}

private async Task getInterpretersAsync()
{
    cbInterpreter.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => MemoryObjects.InterpreterNamesFacadeList);

    cbInterpreter.ValueMember = "IntNo";
    cbInterpreter.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    cbInterpreter.Enabled = true;
}

private async Task getCustomersAsync()
{
    cbCustomer.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => MemoryObjects.CustomerNamesFacadeList);

    cbCustomer.ValueMember = "CustNo";
    cbCustomer.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cbCustomer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to `DoEvents`.  It may be that some handler that's being called as a result of that call is taking a long time

Comment: If I remove the call to DoEvents() then the form loads with all the controls half way rendered and only completes rendering the other controls after the combobox datasources are assigned.  The DoEvents() in the form show event finishes everything up rendering before trying to do the comboboxes.  It doesn't seem to have any effect on the useability of the form, that is, in either case you couldn't say grab the form and drag it around while the comboboxes are loading.

Comment: @Flydog57... this is a plugin for an existing external application though, not a free standing windows form app.  So, maybe something to that?

Comment: What happens if you comment out: `Cursor = Cursors.Default;`? If the cursor is the 'wait' cursor, it means it's blocking. Also, how many items do you have to display?

Comment: @Poul, thanks for suggestion but, I just tried and no effect

Comment: If the cursor is normal, then you can also comment out `Application.DoEvents();` - it does no good, but can do bad things.

Comment: @Poul yea, I guess for now it's just making the form look nice by finishing up the rendering of the controls but, you're right, it's not getting at the real source of the problem which is that when running those async calls it's blocking out the form (e.g. the form is frozen until the async tasks complete)

Comment: Get the async results in variables: `var res = await Task.Run(() => ...;` then assign them to the `DataSource` properties.  I think with the direct assignment, the combo boxes are blocking the msg pump (mainly the redraw ones) until the completion of the async calls. Give it a try. And get rid of `Application.DoEvents();`.

Comment: this.Update() instead of DoEvents().  But that's not the cause of the problem.  We can't see what these tasks actually do.  Could be querying a component that has thread affinity, like an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @Dr.Null it's still clunky but, I think there might be a bit of improvement with your suggestion... testing

Comment: @Hans, it's just a call to a SQL database ADO.NET... the MemoryObjects is a static class that just fills the list if empty or uses the memory resident list if it's already been filled.  I can try to post the code but it's pretty generic.  thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  I think the fact that nobody is pointing out problems with the async calls is telling.  I had assumed the issue was here because I don't use async that often but, the lists are quite large so, now I'm thinking it might be the synchronous  binding of the asynchronously retrieved list to the combobox that is taking the time/blocking.

Comment: *"I think the fact that nobody is pointing out problems with the async calls is telling."* -- What does it tell to you? Your code is excellent as far as async/await is concerned, so there is no problem to speak of. Are we expected to ignore the red herring, and guess that you are trying to load half of the Merriam-Webster in the combo box? Check out this thread at MS forums if you want: [Why does ComboBox introduce intolerable lag when populating???](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/179a7d00-fb15-44d7-bd3d-a8b940d4de8c/)

Comment: @Theodore, yes, I might not have made that as clear as I could have but, it is telling to me that async is not the problem.  I had assumed that this was where the problem lied as I am not particularly experienced in async coding.  It's a refactor of someone else's code and prior to "not seeing" comments relating to my async code, I hadn't considered that the problem lie elsewhere.  After that I found the exact same article you reference above :)

Comment: I am a bit concerned that the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are changed *after* setting the `DataSource`. I don't know for sure, but this might be causing the combo box to redraw itself three times...

Comment: @Theodore, yes I know about that particular issue and have updated my code as such.  It's not the core issue but helpful none the less to set them prior to setting the datasource.  A lot of refactoring, my original post had an error in that respect.

Comment: Check out also the [`BeginUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.beginupdate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)/`EndUpdate` methods. They might be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: [Start a Task in the Form Shown event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103)

Answer (score 1):

I think the (visual) problem is that that the `Shown` event of the form is called before it fully finished painting.

One trick I use in such cases is to use the `Application.Idle` event to call those background jobs instead of using the `Shown` event.

Subscribe to the `Idle event in form` Load`, like this:

```
private void FrmOrderSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ........other code
    Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
}
```

Now the `Idle` event handler:

```
private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Idle -= Application_Idle; // Should only be called once.
    // Add all your background jobs (from the `Shown` event)    
}
```

Now the Application has finished painting before the background jobs are called.

However, this does not fix the real problem, why those background jobs are so slow. We can't help you with that with the current info.

Comment: Thanks Poul, I was focusing on the async tasks because I'm not so good at async but, the lists are very large (~250, 7K and 24K respectively), and I hadn't considered that maybe it's just taking a long time to populate the combobox after the list has been retrieved asynchronously and the async might not be the problem at all.

Comment: Have you tried the 'Idle' trick? Does the form paint fully?

Comment: Yes, the form does fully paint with idle, thanks.  Still frozen but painted.