# Multiform refresh, "Invalid operation between threads"

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I made a sub to refresh multiple Forms using another thread, I know I've to `Invoke` to solve this problem, but I don't know how to invoke in that case... Because I've 3 different forms and multiples controls. How do I solve that?

**Error in compiler:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operação entre threads inválida:
> controle '_procVlrCond' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual
> foi criado.'

**Code:**

```
Public Shared Sub VerificaAlterações(ByVal MOV_Bancos As List(Of Integer), ByVal MOV_Lançamentos As List(Of Integer), ByVal MOV_Datas As List(Of Date), ByVal DOC_Lojas As List(Of Integer), ByVal DOC_Clientes As List(Of Integer), ByVal DOC_BACs As List(Of String), ByVal DOC_Condições As List(Of Integer), ByVal DOC_Datas As List(Of Date), ByVal DOC_Sacados As List(Of String), ByVal DOCS_Documentos As List(Of String), ByVal DOC_Valores As List(Of Decimal))
    Dim n As Integer = 0

    For Each FormRefresh As Form In Application.OpenForms()

        Select Case FormRefresh.Name

            Case Form1.Name
                n = 0
                For Each BAC In DOC_BACs
                    With DirectCast(FormRefresh, Form1)
                        .Btn1.PerformClick()
                    End With
                    n += 1
                Next

            Case Form2.Name
                n = 0
                For Each BAC In DOC_BACs
                    With DirectCast(FormRefresh, Form2)
                        If (.tbLoja.Text = DOC_Lojas(n).ToString OrElse .tbLoja.Text = vbNullString OrElse CInt(.tbLoja.Text) = 0) AndAlso ' Loja
                        (.tbCliente.Text = DOC_Clientes(n).ToString OrElse .tbCliente.Text = vbNullString OrElse CInt(.tbCliente.Text) = 0) AndAlso ' Cliente
                        (._procNome.Text = vbNullString OrElse ._procNome.Text.Contains(DOC_Sacados(n))) AndAlso ' Nome
                        (._procDcto.Text = vbNullString OrElse ._procNome.Text.Contains(DOCS_Documentos(n))) AndAlso ' Documento
                        (._procVlrCond.SelectedIndex = 0) AndAlso ' Intervalor de valor (qualquer apenas)
                        (._pVenc1.Checked = False OrElse ._pVenc1.Value <= DOC_Datas(n)) AndAlso ' Vencimento Inicial
                        (._pVenc2.Checked = False OrElse ._pVenc2.Value >= DOC_Datas(n)) AndAlso ' Vencimento Final
                           .BTN_Pesquisar.PerformClick() Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End With
                    n += 1
                Next

            Case Form3.Name
                n = 0
                For Each BAC In DOC_BACs
                    With DirectCast(FormRefresh, Form3)
                        For Each Linha As DataGridViewRow In .tabDocumentos.Rows
                            ' Pintar células
                            With Linha.DefaultCellStyle
                                .ForeColor = Color.Black
                                .SelectionBackColor = Color.Black
                            End With
                        Next
                    End With
                Next

        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You *could* use the `FormRefresh` reference. But, why do you think you need *threads* for this. The only thing that's actually happening is that you invoke back to the UI Thread, nothing is actually computed here. What you need to offload to a worker Task / Thread is the elaboration of data, then marshal the data back to the UI Thread. When you have something like this: `For Each Linha As DataGridViewRow In .tabDocumentos.Rows`, this all needs to be executed in the Thread that owns those Controls, a worker thread that just invokes it not simply useless...

Comment: Also, you should not loop the Rows collection of a DataGridView, you should use, e.g., the `RowPostPaint` event to color the Rows based on some changing *states*, so you don't *loop the Rows*, you just change a state (a Field variable) which, when set to different values, affects the presentation of the whole grid. To see it applied when conditions change, you simply invalidate the Control.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks a lot for the tip about the row painting, I'll implement it in all my code! About the threads, I'm using it because I think it's faster, the sub will execute in another thread, allowing user to keep using the system without waiting... But I think I'm doing it wrong... I'll study and try to solve this...

Comment: As mentioned, a worker thread can be used to elaborate data that is then sent to the thread that owns the presentation surface (the UI). But it's not useful to have a thread that simply invokes the UI thread to perform updates. The actual work is still done in the UI Thread, you simply add overhead, when it's the UI Thread that still performs the actual work. As described, in relation to painting the Rows of a DataGridView, you have to keep your procedures as simple as possible. You don't show any elaboration of data here, just changes that involve the UI Thread directly. So, not useful

Comment: See the first two methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103) (not *perfect*, just samples of possible different procedures) -- Another couple of methods show how invoking the UI Thread could work (though not suggested), to perform updates in batches, in different *styles* -- I cannot suggest what to do in your specific case, because I have no idea where the data you're using to update the UI comes from

Comment: Using a second thread is not faster. Generally speaking, a second thread is used to process data while the UI thread remains available to process the UI. Processing the data still takes the same amount of time. It's using multiple threads to process the data in parallel that will generally be faster, but your not doing that. The problem is that all the work your doing is on the UI. As you have realised, you would need to use Invoke, so you're back on the UI thread anyway and the second thread is useless. Get rid of the second thread. It's a nice idea but can't help in this case.

Comment: You should get rid of virtually all that code. If a form needs to be "refreshed" then you should write a method in that form to do that. The code here would then simply call that method. You could even declare that method in an interface that is implemented in each form, so you can cast every form as that type and do away with the type checking.

Comment: The porpuse of this sub is: You've a form (FormInsertDelete) which you insert/delete data in DB and some other forms (FormSelect1, FormSelect2) which you select some data from DB. When you insert a value in database using FormInsertDelete form, all other forms refreshes to show/hide this value, it's when I use this sub... So, all insert/delete work in FormInsertDelete is done by main thread while all refreshes work done in FormSelect's is done my another thread, but to refresh other forms, I've to interfere in UI, that's why I'm having problem with "Invoke"... @jmcilhinney

Comment: I explain my case above @Jimi

Comment: Based on that description, there may be no need to for any code at all. If the amount of data is not too large, you could populate a single `DataTable` and then use that in all your forms. If you want to insert a new record, you add it to the `DataTable` first and then all forms that bind it will update automatically. Even if it's not bound, a form can handle an appropriate event and update itself when the `DataTable` changes. You then use a data adapter to save the changes in the `DataTable` back to the database.

Comment: Regardless, I don't see a reason for this method to be `Shared` and, at most, it should simply be making a single method call to each form and then each form decides for itself what needs to be done. If there was any multithreading or parallelism to be implemented, it would be done in each individual form and only involve the processing of data, not the presentation of that data.

Comment: As explained, you're probably using the wrong tools. You modify the data that is bound to your Control, then you update the database, using, e.g., the [Update()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.update) method of a [DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter) or the corresponding update method of an EntityFramework / other ORM data model, depending on how you're managing the source of data. You don't touch the UI directly, there's no need for it. Update notifications are (or can be) self-propagating

Comment: In other words, see how data bindings work in this platform

Comment: About the `DataTable` idea, I think it's not going to work for me, because in one form I only select data from one table, in the other, I select and join with another table... All the tables have different number of columns and etc... @jmcilhinney

Comment: Yes, I'm not using `Update()` method because the updates that I'm doing is from another form which have an insert user interface... I've one form for insert and another form for search (select)... I don't know if that's the best practice but If I'm going to change it, I think I've to merge those forms, that'll take weeks :(... I've some problems with my program, because I learned to program in it, I'm trying to make with faster/efficient, even if that take time, the only problem is that I don't know exacly what're the best practices.  @Jimi

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you have multiple Forms or not, data bindings don't have this kind of boundaries. If you cannot get automatic notifications of updates (through data bindings), then repeat the query that loads the data. if you have problems with that, too, then your data structure needs to be refactored, because it's creating obstacles to the functionality of the application (happens when you have deigned the two things separately, without a complete vision of their combined roles)