# How should I call a delegate from a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: vb.net, delegates, backgroundworker

I've created a delegate to have a log, the RichTexbox is visible and I want to call the delegate from a BackgroundWorker (DoWork) but is not working.

What should I change to this?

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Delegate Sub WriteRtbLogDelegate(ByVal Texto As String, ByVal _Color As Color)
    
    Private Sub WriteRTBLog(ByVal Texto As String, ByVal TextColor As Color)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim method As WriteRtbLogDelegate = AddressOf Me.WriteRTBLog
            Me.Invoke(method, Texto, TextColor)
        Else
            If RTB_Log.Lines.Length < 1 Then
                'ultima = 0
                RTB_Log.AppendText("Inicio del LOG - " & Now.ToLongDateString & vbCrLf)
            End If
    
            Dim length As Integer = RTB_Log.Text.Length
    
            Texto = Format(Now.Day, "00").ToString & "/" & Format(Now.Month, "00").ToString & "/" & Now.Year.ToString & " - " & Format(Now.Hour, "00").ToString & ":" & Format(Now.Minute, "00").ToString & ":" & Format(Now.Second, "00").ToString &
                                  " " & Texto
            RTB_Log.AppendText(Texto + vbCrLf)
            RTB_Log.SelectionStart = length
            RTB_Log.SelectionLength = Texto.Length
            RTB_Log.SelectionColor = TextColor
            ' The following expression was wrapped in a checked-expression
            RTB_Log.[Select](RTB_Log.SelectionStart + RTB_Log.SelectionLength, 0)
            RTB_Log.SelectionColor = TextColor
            RTB_Log.SelectionLength = 0
            RTB_Log.SelectionStart = RTB_Log.TextLength
            RTB_Log.ScrollToCaret()
    
            If RTB_Log.TextLength > 1000000.0 Then
                With RTB_Log
                    .SaveFile(Application.StartupPath & "\" & Format(Now.Day, "00").ToString & "-" & Format(Now.Month, "00").ToString & "-" & Now.Year.ToString & " - " &
                              Format(Now.Hour, "00").ToString & Format(Now.Minute, "00").ToString & Format(Now.Second, "00").ToString &
                              ".log", System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
                    .Clear()
                    .Text = "Log guardado en " & Application.StartupPath & Now.ToShortDateString & ".log"
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub BGW1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGW1.DoWork
WriteRTBLog("Starting...", Color.Blue)

End Sub
```

I'm getting an exception:

> Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control
> 'RTB_Log' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.

Comment: "... but is not working" Please define HOW it is not working. Does it get an exception? What are you expecting to happen that is not happening?

Comment: "... and I want to call the delegate from a BackgroundWorker (DoWork)" You haven't shown us the call to `WriteRTBLog()` in your `DoWork()` handler.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I added part of the DoWork() code. And, yes, I'm getting an exception. _Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'RTB_Log' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó._

Comment: A simple test case with your code does NOT generate a cross-thread exception for me. You must be doing something else not quite right. How are you starting the background worker control? Any other threading going on?

Comment: Why don't you use the [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress) method (and related event + `[BackgroundWorker].WorkerReportsProgress = true`) instead of this contraption? -- Or, better still, run a Task and use a [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate for the updates

Comment: @Idle_Mind No, There's like 10 variables declared and a Function is called before to get a number from the database.

Comment: @Jimi I will try that. Can I pass string and color to that routine?

Comment: You can pass whatever you want. I suggest a class object that contains all required properties. Also easier to extend if / when required -- See the first snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103) for an implementation

Comment: You need to translate your error messages before posting them, not leave it to every person who reads this question to do it for themselves.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you shouldn't. The whole point of the `BackgroundWorker` is to do multithreading without using delegates directly. You're supposed to call methods and handle events, which everyone has done before. If you want to do something during the background work, call `ReportProgess` and handle `ProgressChanged`. If you want to do something after the background work then handle `RunWorkerCompleted`. That's why the `BackgroundWorker` exists in the first place.

Comment: FWIW, the exception is the standard cross-thread GUI operation exception.  If you do a search on it, you should find plenty of answers on how to eliminate the exception.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was thinking in to do a translation before post but usually the translation is not like the same error in English word by word. Should I do it anyway?

Comment: A translated error message that isn't 100% accurate is better than an error message in a language that most people can't read at all. Most people will have to use a translator anyway and that should be done once by you, rather then every time someone reads the question and taking up their time when they're trying to help you. It will usually be the case that the translation will be close enough that we can recognise the exception and what the original message would be if it were in English.